# birt report - fade background colour of table cells

Tags: colors, background, report, gradient, birt

Basically what I want to do is to apply some sort of styling, from either top to bottom or right to left, which goes from say dark blue to light blue.

Is this at all possible without using a separate image file for each cell of a table?

I'm using BIRT 3.7.1

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only do this at view time, you can attach an external CSS file. In the report, go to your Style section and choose "Use CSS file". Otherwise you need to use a background image.